# How to generate query errors in php

Tags: php, mysql

i have a query that doesn't seem to be executing for some reason. I've checked all the vars are the right names, that they all have the right data in them but for some reason it just won't fire.

Now i know there is a way to generate the error but i can't remember or find it on the internet. I'm using mysqli to run the query are this is the code for the query:

```
$stmt = $this->conn->query("INSERT INTO seminar_signup(email, firstname, surname, address_1, address_2, postcode) VALUES ('$san_email', '$san_firstname', '$san_surname', '$san_address1', '$san_address2', '$san_postcode')");
```

I've more or less copied the code from another function that does close to the same thing and that works fine.

thanks for the help.

Comment: What kind of object is $this -> conn?  A MySQLi instance?  A PDO instance?  A custom-built object that extends one of the above objects?  A custom-built object that doesn't extend either of the above?

Comment: You have a query, try it directly on MySQL, you just need to replace dummy data in that variables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this: [mysqli error](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php)

Answer (score 1):

try to
$stmt = $this->conn->query("INSERT INTO seminar_signup(email, firstname, surname, address_1, address_2, postcode) VALUES ('".$san_email."', '".$san_firstname."', '".$san_surname."', '".$san_address1."', '".$san_address2."', '".$san_postcode."')");

Answer (score 0):

```
$stmt = @$this->conn->query("INSERT INTO seminar_signup(email, firstname, surname, address_1, address_2, postcode) VALUES ('$san_email', '$san_firstname', '$san_surname', '$san_address1', '$san_address2', '$san_postcode')");

echo mysql_error();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$stmt = $this->conn->query("INSERT INTO seminar_signup(email, firstname, surname, address_1, address_2, postcode) VALUES ('$san_email', '$san_firstname', '$san_surname', '$san_address1', '$san_address2', '$san_postcode')") or die(mysql_error());
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the same query directly on MySQL, If you still want to get errors in PHP following are the MySQLi functions to get last errors

[mysqli::$errno — Returns the error code for the most recent function call](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.errno.php)
[mysqli::$error_list — Returns a list of errors from the last command executed](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error-list.php)
[mysqli::$error — Returns a string description of the last error](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php)

Answer (score 0):

First check the connection is it opened

then get the sql query by echo which is going to execute in your query function of $this->conn, and execute it in your phpmyadmin or what ever GUI you have.